# How to access custom element with hypen in name using Ruby Page-Object Gem

Tags: ruby, angular, watir, page-object-gem

I have some angular elements and I want to map them. Trying to do it like so

`element('ng-select', id: 'id1')`

Getting an error about Watir

`NameError: undefined local variable or method 'ng' for #<Watir::HTMLElement:0x04defcc8>`

That's right. Error says '`ng`', NOT '`ng-select`'. What gives? How can I specify that the `ng-select` tag? I know I can replace `ng-select` with `element` but that seems too generic for me. The page-object gem already doesn't have native support for angular tags so I'd like to be descriptive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first argument in `#element` is used as the method name for a locating an element in Watir. For example:

```
element('element', id: 'id1') #=> translates to browser.element(id: 'id1')
element('div', id: 'id1') #=> translates to browser.div(id: 'id1')
```

With 'ng-select', it is blindly applied resulting in running the following. There is an exception since `#ng` does not exist.

```
browser.ng - select(id: 'id1')
```

Technically, the first argument is the corresponding Watir method, not just a tag name. If you want a custom tag name, pass it as part of the locator:

```
element(:element, tag_name: 'ng-select', id: 'id1')
```